SSIS flat file destination sort order
This is an SSIS 2017 issue using a Flat File Destination.
We pull the data from an OLD DB Source, run the column through a Sort Transformation and send the result to a Flat File Destination.
In all my testing I'm finding that the order in the resultant text file is correct.
I've used up to one million rows of random data and the sort order is always correct.
My boss, who has used SSIS for many years, says that this is not guaranteed because of the buffering of data in SSIS and we will have to use a scripting method to guarantee the sort order in the test file.
Do any of you know if this is true or not, or perhaps in older versions it was true, but this has been fixed.

If you sort the data (or tell SSIS it's sorted to start with and it really is) of course it's sorted. And yes, SSIS writes that data in that sorted order.

For some reason, he's saying that when dealing with flat files the buffer may not guarantee the order of the records.  This is not what I have found.  Do you know anywhere something like this is discussed?

No, because I'm confident what your manager is telling you isn't true. Have you asked them for references?

No I haven't, he just says he knows this because of the many years he has used SSIS.  Thank you for your reply, it was very helpful!
